# startx (xinit) on debian bookworm: where should I add a call to xrandr?

Tags: debian, xrandr, startx, xinit, alternatives

tl;dr: Is `~/.xsessionrc` the **only place** to add a call to `xrandr` *without* breaking `startx`'s connection to my `x-{session,window}-manager` alternatives?

I start my window manager on Debian Bookworm by logging in on `vt1`/`tty1` and running `startx`. I use the Debian Alternatives System's `x-session-manager` and `x-window-manager` alternatives to determine which of my installed window managers I will use for the current session.

I now need to *add in* a call to `xrandr` somewhere in the `startx` call chain **before the window manager starts** (if I add the `xrandr` invocation as the first line in the window manager's config file, then the `xrandr` call happens too late, the window manager gets confused and the window layout breaks).

I have studyied the contents of the `xinit` package, the files under `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` and [johnraff's excellent explanation](https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=3774), and I have come to the conclusion that if I add/modify `~/.xinitrc`, `~/.xsession` or `~/.Xsession` then `startx` will not start my window manager (Both `~/.xsession` or `~/.Xsession` will override the Debian Alternatives System, and `~/.xinitrc` completely stops the contents of `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` from being processed). That leaves `~/.xsessionrc` as the **only place** where I can add a call to `xrandr` without breaking `startx`'s connection to my `x-{session,window}-manager` alternatives. Is this correct?